# VSBuild Fails with Error MSB4057 When Building with Azure Pipelines ('The target "<project_name>" does not exist in the project')

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, yaml

I am trying to run the VSBuild@1 task in an Azure Pipeline and every time it fails with the same error - "The target "<project_name>" does not exist in the project". I've searched for every answer to this question and none have worked for me. The exact yaml I'm running is

```
- task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build Project1 and Project2'
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/t:Folder\Project1:Rebuild;Folder\Project2:Rebuild'
        clean: true
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The directory looks like 'Repo\Folder\Project1\Project1.csproj' and 'Repo\Folder\Project2\Project2.csproj' and the VSBuild version is 1.199.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
set MSBuildEmitSolution=1
msbuild All.sln /t:<project_name>
```

Then search in the generated All.sln.metaproj file the exact target names () of all projects you want to build.  After that you can build projects:

```
msbuild All.sln /t:"<project_name>" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

Comment: Trying to run this gets me an error saying "error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: All.sln" Also tried with the actual .sln names and same result. It works if I manually click and select "Build".

Comment: I got the command to work, I think, but I could not find any generated .metaproj file.